What are the different symbiotes in the Venom : The Last Dance movie?
What are the different symbiotes shown in Venom: The Last Dance movie and what are their powers? We are shown a lot of symbiotes being captured in the Area 55 and in the fight against the Xenophages. What are the name of these symbiotes and what are their powers?
